# Scraped Span Returns None Get_Text() Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've scraped links to cars and now wish to follow the links and scrape some data about each car but my code returns an empty array (None if i print individually). Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.25thstauto.com/inventory.aspx?cursort=asc&pagesize=500').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

car = soup.select('a[id*=ctl00_cphBody_inv1_rptInventoryNew]')         
for a in car:
    source2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.25thstauto.com/'+a.get('href')).read()
    price.append(soup.find('span', {'id': 'ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice'}))
    print(price)
```

Comment: A couple of things: have you printed out the `source` variable to confirm that you are receiving the actual page? (I have had many times where I have been trying to scrape a page only to realize that I am not getting back a proper HTML response. This can usually be resolved by including a user-agent along with the request to better replicate a browser.) Next, have you confirmed that you have the `lxml` HTML parser properly installed and configured? (Refer to [the installation documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib

source = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.25thstauto.com/inventory.aspx?cursort=asc&pagesize=500').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
price = []
car = soup.select('a[id*=ctl00_cphBody_inv1_rptInventoryNew]')         
for a in car:
    source2 = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.25thstauto.com/'+a.get('href')).read()
    # make a new soup baesd on the link, do not use old soup
    soup2 = bs.BeautifulSoup(source2, 'lxml')
    price.append(soup2.find('span', {'id': 'ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice'}))
    print(price)
```

out:

```
[<span id="ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice">$2,995</span>]
[<span id="ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice">$2,995</span>, <span id="ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice">$2,995</span>]
[<span id="ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice">$2,995</span>, <span id="ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice">$2,995</span>, <span id="ctl00_cphBody_inv1_lblPrice">$2,995</span>]
```

Comment: scrape king strikes again! do you have a git hub?

Comment: @Sean Kelly no, I am not active in github. and please accept the answer.